# Data Type Matching (Excel Column X Sql Server Column)

Tags: c#, sql

### I have a following Issue.

I have written a code for Exporting Excel sheet to Sql Server but it meaningless dumping because I am not comparing data types.
 At middle I wrote store procedure seems It gives Exception but I want strict Column Mismatching Error. 
Like Column Number 10 Data type not matched.
 The Problem is that all values retrieved from excel sheet is dumped in String .
 Is any body give me solution for the same?(How I specify or Retrieve column data type from Excel Sheet? )

Comment: Create a custom exception?

Comment: @spaceBison I have already write a code for it but I need to Match data type even all values from Excel is in String. Will you have another solution for the same?

Comment: Most (all?) primitive types in .NET have .Parse and .TryParse methods. They take a string as input and try to convert it to the appropriate type.

Comment: @Marton Sir. I will try for It.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive types in .NET have `.Parse` and `.TryParse` methods. They take a string as input and try to convert it to the appropriate type.

A parsing operation converts a string that represents a .NET Framework base type into that base type. For example, a parsing operation is used to convert a string to a floating-point number or to a date and time value. The method most commonly used to perform a parsing operation is the Parse method.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4w53z0y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - Parsing strings in the .NET Framework

An example is the Int32.TryParse method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx